# CheckboxList RepeatColumns Issue In Responsive Design

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a mobile responsive design for a website, here I have multiple checkboxes on a page.I have used a checkboxlist for multiple checkboxes.But the design(width/repeat column property)
of checkboxlist is not coming according to Mobile/ tablet screen width/Resolution. This may be because of the Repeat column property set to some number.

How can I set the repeat column property so that my checkboxlist width comes according to the display of Mobile/ tablet screen width/Resolution. Or Should I have to use CheckBox Control instead of CheckboxList.

Thanks,

Comment: i have same problem can anybody help?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. Possibly show us some snapshot or some live demo.

Comment: Can't you just set width to 100% via CSS?

Answer (score 0):

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          System.Windows.Forms.Screen sr = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen;
            int width = sr.Bounds.Width;
            int height = sr.Bounds.Height;
            if (width > 0 && width <= 768)
            {
                chkboxlstCuisineTypes.RepeatColumns = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                chkboxlstCuisineTypes.RepeatColumns = 3;
            }
         }
```